# with spring boot 2.1 and angular 6 if i logged in angular login page

Tags: spring, angular6

with spring boot 2.1 and angular 6 if i logged in angular login page how to access all authenticated spring(RequestMaping) pages without login every page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //by adding headers in http from front (angular)
 let headers=new HttpHeaders({
'Authorization':localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
 });
 //'Authorization' is added when you login at first time you add 
let encodedCredential=btoa(username+":"+password);
let basicHeader='Basic '+encodedCredential;
localStorage.setItem('Authorization',basicHeader);
```